# Nested for loops to recursive function in Python

Tags: python, recursion, nested-loops

I have three lists, each one with several possible values.

```
probs = ([0.1,0.1,0.2], \
         [0.7,0.9], \
         [0.5,0.4,0.1])
```

I want to test all possible combinations of choosing one element from each list. So, 3*2*3=18 possible combinations in this example. In the end, I want to choose the most favourable combinations according to some criteria. This is:

```
[<index in row 0> , <index in row 1> , <index in row 2> , <criteria value>]
```

I can accomplish my task by using three nested for loops (which I did). However, in the real application of this code, I will have a variable number of lists. Because of that, it seems the solution would be using a recursive function with a for loop inside it (which I did as well). The code:

```
# three rows. Test all combinations of one element from each row
# This is [value form row0, value from row1, value from row2]
# So: 3*2*3 = 18 possible combinations
probs = ([0.1,0.1,0.2], \
         [0.7,0.9], \
         [0.5,0.4,0.1])

meu = [] # The list that will store the best combinations in the recursion


#######################################################

def main():

    choice = [] #the list that will store the best comb in the nested for

# accomplish by nested for loops

    for n0 in range(len(probs[0])):
        for n1 in range(len(probs[1])):
            for n2 in range(len(probs[2])):

                w = probs[0][n0] * probs[1][n1] * probs[2][n2]
                cmb = [n0,n1,n2,w]
                if len(choice) == 0:
                    choice.append(cmb)
                elif len(choice) < 5:
                    for i in range(len(choice)+1):
                        if i == len(choice):
                            choice.append(cmb)
                            break
                        if w < choice[i][3]:
                            choice.insert(i,cmb)
                            break
                else:
                    for i in range(len(choice)):
                        if w < choice[i][3]:
                            choice.insert(i,cmb)
                            del choice[-1]
                            break            


# using recursive function
    combinations(0,[])


    #both results
    print('By loops:')
    print(choice)
    print('By recursion:')
    print(meu)



#######################################################


def combinations(step,cmb):

    # Why does 'meu' needs to be global

    if step < len(probs):
        for i in range(len(probs[step])):
            cmb = cmb[0:step] # I guess this is the same problem I dont understand recursion
                                # But, unlike 'meu', here I could use this workaround
            cmb.append(i)
            combinations(step+1,cmb)


    else:
            w = 1
            for n in range(len(cmb)):
                w *= probs[n][cmb[n]]
            cmb.append(w)

            if len(meu) == 0:
                meu.append(cmb)
            elif len(meu) < 5:
                for i in range(len(meu)+1):
                    if i == len(meu):
                        meu.append(cmb)
                        break
                    if w < meu[i][-1]:
                        meu.insert(i,cmb)
                        break
            else:
                for i in range(len(meu)):
                    if w < meu[i][-1]:
                        meu.insert(i,cmb)
                        del meu[-1]
                        break

            return


######################################################

main()
```

It outputs, as I wanted:

```
By loops:
[[0, 0, 2, 0.006999999999999999], [1, 0, 2, 0.006999999999999999], [0, 1, 2, 0.009000000000000001], [1, 1, 2, 0.009000000000000001], [2, 0, 2, 0.013999999999999999]]
By recursion:
[[0, 0, 2, 0.006999999999999999], [1, 0, 2, 0.006999999999999999], [0, 1, 2, 0.009000000000000001], [1, 1, 2, 0.009000000000000001], [2, 0, 2, 0.013999999999999999]]
```

Initially, I wanted to use the 'meu' list as internal of the function, because, I thought, it would be better to avoid global variables (perhaps not... I'm a newbie). The problem was I could not come up with a code that would pass both 'meu' and 'cmb' between depths to give the same effect of the nested loops.

How could I implement a recursive function with internal 'meu' instead of being a global list? What am I missing from recursion concept? Thanks.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Example of a failed function:

```
def combinations(choice,step,cmb):

    if step < len(probs):
        for i in range(len(probs[step])):
            cmb = cmb[0:step] #workaroud for cmb
            cmb.append(i)
            choice = combinations(choice,step+1,cmb)

    else:
            w = 1
            for n in range(len(cmb)):
                w *= probs[n][cmb[n]]
            cmb.append(w)

            if len(choice) == 0:
                choice.append(cmb)
            elif len(choice) < 5:
                for i in range(len(choice)+1):
                    if i == len(choice):
                        choice.append(cmb)
                        break
                    if w < choice[i][-1]:
                        choice.insert(i,cmb)
                        break
            else:
                for i in range(len(choice)):
                    if w < choice[i][-1]:
                        choice.insert(i,cmb)
                        del choice[-1]
                        break

            return choice
```

Called by:

```
choice = combinations([],0,[])
```

Comment: Sorry, you say 'meu' in many places, but I can't seem to find it in the code. Also, can you check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python] as it might give you some additional tools from python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. kindall response and also your link suggestion answered my problem. But answering your question, 'meu' is inside the 'combinations' functions in the longest code section I presented.

Comment: @ direito Completely overlooked it :-) Sorry. Glad you got your solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel (recursively or not): use the included batteries. The problem you are trying to solve is extremely common and so a solution is included in Python's standard library.

What you want—every combination of every value from some number of lists—is called the Cartesian product of those lists. `itertools.product` exists to generate those for you.

```
import itertools

probs = ([0.1, 0.1, 0.2],
         [0.7, 0.9],
         [0.5, 0.4, 0.1])

for prob in itertools.product(*probs):
    print prob
    # prob is a tuple containing one combination of the variables
    # from each of the input lists, do with it what you will
```

If you want to know what index each item comes from, the easiest way is to just pass the indices to `product()` rather than the values. You can easily get that using `range()`.

```
for indices in itertools.product(*(range(len(p)) for p in probs)):
    # get the values corresponding to the indices
    prob = [probs[x][indices[x]] for x in range(len(probs))]
    print indices, prob
```

Or you could use `enumerate()` -- this way, each item in the product is a tuple containing its index and its values (not two separate lists the way you get them in the above method):

```
 for item in itertools.product(*(enumerate(p) for p in probs)):
     print item
```

Comment: Yes, that it, thank you!! In the resulting prob (say [0.2,0.7,0.4]), is it possible to know the original indexes in probs (this is [2,0,1])? Or do I have to create an auxiliar list to help me: aux = ([0,1,2],[0,1],[0,1,2])?

Comment: You could use `enumerate` for that. I'll see if I can grab a minute to add an example.

Comment: @direito -- Updated with a couple additional examples.